# Unable to get itemData from owner-drawn combobox

Tags: winapi

I have an owner-drawn combobox created with `CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` and **without** `CBS_HASSTRINGS`.

This combobox is supposed to display a list of top-level windows of the running processes. I keep relevant information about this windows (icon, title, handle) in a class called `RunningProcess`. This is the code that populates the combobox:

```
void populateProcessList(HWND combobox) {
    SendMessage(combobox, CB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);

    std::vector<RunningProcess*> topLevelWindows = RunningProcesses::enumerateTopLevelWindows();
    for (int index = 0; index < topLevelWindows.size(); index++) {
        RunningProcess *proc = topLevelWindows[index];
        SendMessage(combobox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)proc);
    }
}
```

MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647527(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> If you create the combo box with an owner-drawn style but without the `CBS_HASSTRINGS` style, the value of the `lParam` parameter is stored as item data rather than the string it would otherwise point to. The item data can be retrieved or modified by sending the `CB_GETITEMDATA` or `CB_SETITEMDATA` message.

Now when I capture the `WM_DRAWITEM` message, I use this snippet to get the `RunningProcess` object and use the data inside

```
LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
RunningProcess *proc = (RunningProcess*)lpdis->itemData;
```

Obviously, the debugger shows that the memory cannot be read, because otherwise I wouldn't be here asking for help!

Could you help me out with this? Please, tell me if there is anything else you need in order to understand my problem better!

P.S. Here is `enumerateTopLevelWindows` function and some of its dependencies:

```
BOOL RunningProcesses::processWindows(HWND window, LPARAM lParam) {
    std::vector<RunningProcess*>& windows = *(std::vector<RunningProcess*>*)lParam;

    TCHAR windowTitle[260];
    HICON windowIcon;

    GetWindowText(window, windowTitle, 260);
    windowIcon = RunningProcesses::getAppIcon(window);

    windows.push_back(new RunningProcess(window, windowTitle, windowIcon));
    return TRUE;
}

std::vector<RunningProcess*> RunningProcesses::enumerateTopLevelWindows() {
    std::vector<RunningProcess*> windows;
    BOOL ret = EnumWindows(RunningProcesses::processWindows, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&windows));

    return windows;
}

HICON RunningProcesses::getAppIcon(HWND window) {
    HICON iconHandle = (HICON)SendMessage(window, WM_GETICON, ICON_SMALL2, 0);
    if (iconHandle == nullptr)
        iconHandle = (HICON)SendMessage(window, WM_GETICON, ICON_SMALL, 0);
    if (iconHandle == nullptr)
        iconHandle = (HICON)SendMessage(window, WM_GETICON, ICON_BIG, 0);
    if (iconHandle == nullptr)
        iconHandle = (HICON)GetClassLongPtr(window, GCL_HICON);
    if (iconHandle == nullptr)
        iconHandle = (HICON)GetClassLongPtr(window, GCL_HICONSM);

    if (iconHandle == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    return iconHandle;
}
```

The `RunningProcess` class is as follows:

```
class RunningProcess {
public:
    RunningProcess(HWND hWnd, TCHAR* windowTitle, HICON windowIcon) {
        m_hWnd = hWnd;
        lstrcpy(m_windowTitle, windowTitle);
        m_windowIcon = windowIcon;
    }
    ~RunningProcess();

    const TCHAR* getTitle() const { return m_windowTitle; }

    const char* getTitleMb() const {
        unsigned bufferLen = lstrlen(m_windowTitle);
        char *mbTitle = new char[bufferLen + 1];
        wcstombs(mbTitle, m_windowTitle, bufferLen + 1);

        return mbTitle;
    }
    const HWND getHandle() const { return m_hWnd; }
    const HICON getIcon() const { return m_windowIcon; }

private:
    HWND m_hWnd;
    TCHAR m_windowTitle[260];
    HICON m_windowIcon;
};
```

Comment: Presumably these objects no longer exist. It's not at all obvious how you manage lifetime. We can't see enumerateTopLevelWindows.

Comment: `enumerateTopLevelWindows` returns that `std::vector`, I can post it as well...

Comment: A [mcve] is needed. I can see what the function returns, but I can't see how the lifetime is managed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I hope the edit helps you

Comment: Still can't see enough. Now we need to see RunningProcess

Comment: See my edit, please!

Comment: I can't see why you'd get an AV. It looks like the code leaks like crazy mind you. Anyway, I'm out of enthusiasm here. With no [mcve] this game of 20 questions has not proved productive. Good luck.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is the atitude of the typical guy who only wants to praise himself, and is not actually interested in helping someone

Comment: If you look at my profile here you might find evidence to the contrary. I have no interest at all in helping one individual. I am more interested in helping others in the future. That's what this site is about. With your experience here you should know this. The lack of detail on your question was a problem. You can't admit that. Fine. Your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you not check `lpdis->itemID` for `-1` value. sure you crash in this case. your code must be like this

```
PDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis = (PDRAWITEMSTRUCT) lParam;
if (lpdis->itemID == -1)
{
  // assert (lpdis->itemData == MAXULONG_PTR);
}
else
{
  RunningProcess *proc = (RunningProcess*)lpdis->itemData;
}
```

general rules how debug this cases:
in your `RunningProcess` constructor and destructor add `DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);` for view address of all objects created and destroyed. and compare `lpdis->itemData` on crash with this addresses - and you just view - are you already delete object or `lpdis->itemData` complete invalid (never point on any `RunningProcess` even deleted). in your case i sure that  `lpdis->itemData == MAXULONG_PTR` and `lpdis->itemID == -1`